# await SendAsync does not await on TPL Dataflow BatchBlock

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

The example program has the following BatchBlock: `new BatchBlock<int>(10, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions { MaxNumberOfGroups = 2 });`, to which there are 60 int data items being sent and on a separate task consumed.

The issue is that the `await sourceBlock.SendAsync(i);`, doesn't seem to be awaiting, even though BatchBlock bounded capacity is reached the data is still being continuously sent without consuming task taking out any items first. Eventually the BatchBlock receives only 2 batches of 10 int data items. I would expect `await sourceBlock.SendAsync(i);` to pause execution when 20 items are sent, as bounded capacity of the block is set to 10 with the maximum of 2 groups. Then at some point consuming task would receive the data and the process would repeat.

I have attached the code below, create a simple console app, add the following to the main:

`BatchBlockIssueReplication().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

The method to call:

```
    public static async Task BatchBlockIssueReplication()
    {
        var sourceBlock = new BatchBlock<int>(10, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions { MaxNumberOfGroups = 2 });

        // Reading data from the source block
        Task fireAndForget = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!sourceBlock.Completion.IsCanceled)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1500);
                if (await sourceBlock.OutputAvailableAsync() && sourceBlock.TryReceiveAll(out var results))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: ");
                    foreach (var result in results)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"{result.Length} ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending {i} to the source block");
            await sourceBlock.SendAsync(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished sending data to the source block");

        await Task.Delay(10000);
    }
```

Comment: You haven't set the BoundedCapacity anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the [BoundedCapacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity(v=vs.110).aspx), which controls how many items can wait in the *input* buffer. Exceeding that will make `SendAsync` await.

You set the [MaxNumberOfGroups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.groupingdataflowblockoptions.maxnumberofgroups(v=vs.110).aspx) property which is how many groups this block is going to generate before refusing to receive any other input.

From the docs :

> Gets or sets the maximum number of groups that should be generated by the block.

If you want your block to keep eg 20 blocks in the inputbuffer and wait, you should set BoundedCapacity :

```
var sourceBlock = new BatchBlock<int>(10, new GroupingDataflowBlockOptions 
                                          { 
                                              BoundedCapacity = 20 
                                          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the max is reached `await sourceBlock.SendAsync(i);` is not going to pause since the block actively refuses more items. When this happens `SendAsync` returns `false` indicating the block will not accept new messages. If you write out the the result of the `SendAsync` call you can see where the block stops taking new messages:

```
Sending 0 to the source block
True
Sending 1 to the source block
True
Sending 2 to the source block
True
Sending 3 to the source block
True
Sending 4 to the source block
True
Sending 5 to the source block
True
Sending 6 to the source block
True
Sending 7 to the source block
True
Sending 8 to the source block
True
Sending 9 to the source block
True
Sending 10 to the source block
True
Sending 11 to the source block
True
Sending 12 to the source block
True
Sending 13 to the source block
True
Sending 14 to the source block
True
Sending 15 to the source block
True
Sending 16 to the source block
True
Sending 17 to the source block
True
Sending 18 to the source block
True
Sending 19 to the source block
True
Sending 20 to the source block
False
Sending 21 to the source block
False
Sending 22 to the source block
False
Sending 23 to the source block
False
Sending 24 to the source block
False
Sending 25 to the source block
False
Sending 26 to the source block
False
Sending 27 to the source block
False
Sending 28 to the source block
False
Sending 29 to the source block
False
Sending 30 to the source block
False
Sending 31 to the source block
False
Sending 32 to the source block
False
Sending 33 to the source block
False
Sending 34 to the source block
False
Sending 35 to the source block
False
Sending 36 to the source block
False
Sending 37 to the source block
False
Sending 38 to the source block
False
Sending 39 to the source block
False
Sending 40 to the source block
False
Sending 41 to the source block
False
Sending 42 to the source block
False
Sending 43 to the source block
False
Sending 44 to the source block
False
Sending 45 to the source block
False
Sending 46 to the source block
False
Sending 47 to the source block
False
Sending 48 to the source block
False
Sending 49 to the source block
False
Sending 50 to the source block
False
Sending 51 to the source block
False
Sending 52 to the source block
False
Sending 53 to the source block
False
Sending 54 to the source block
False
Sending 55 to the source block
False
Sending 56 to the source block
False
Sending 57 to the source block
False
Sending 58 to the source block
False
Sending 59 to the source block
False
Finished sending data to the source block
Received: 
10 10
```